# Change real camera resolution in OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, camera

I'm trying to take 4k pictures using OpenCV, but when I change the resolution, the pictures just look resized instead of better quality.

I'm using OpenCV version 4, Python 3.6, Logitech BRIO 4k webcam and Windows 10.

If I don't change the camera resolution, it defaults to 640 x 480. If I change the resolution, the pictures just look blurred like they have been resized and not actually better quality. I can use the "Camera" app on Windows 10 to verify that the camera works with 4k resolution.

Here's what I'm doing:

```py
import cv2
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cam.set(3, 3840)
cam.set(4, 2160)
cv2.namedWindow("test")

while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    cv2.imshow("test", frame)

    if not ret:
        break
    k = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if k%256 == 32:
        # SPACE pressed
        img_name = "opencv_frame.png"
        cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
        print("{} written!".format(img_name))
```

I'd like to be able to change the actual resolution of the pictures.

Comment: It's really poor practice to use hard-coded constants as it makes code really hard to read and also causes massive maintenance issues when libraries and APIs change... I am referring to `cam.set(3,...)` instead of `CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH`

Comment: I am experiencing a similar issue with the same Brio/Python/Win setup. While the resolution will change for me to some variants, images become cropped compared to what displays in OBS/Camera. I am searching for a solution and wondering if it's related to Brio's use of MJPEG and [OpenCV Issue 7013](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/7013)

Comment: Have you tried forcing directshow?  cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

Comment: Forcing direct show seems to be working. I'm getting much better pictures after using cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW). Thanks!

Comment: I experienced the same issue earlier, and I switched to gstreamer pipeline with opencv to get frame of desired size, and fps.

Comment: DSHOW also worked for me, after I updated to OpenCV 4