# Issue to take picture with 4k resolution using Logitech Brio webcam and "pygame" in python

Tags: python, pygame, webcam, brio

I am using "pygame" in python (the code below) to take an image with 4k resolution using Logitech Brio webcam.

```
# take picture using pygame
import time
import cv2 
import pygame
import pygame.camera
from pygame.locals import *

start_time = time.time()

pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()

cam = pygame.camera.Camera(0,(4096, 2160))
cam.start()
image = cam.get_image()
path = 'C:/Users/aatefi2/Downloads/robot_images/'
imageName = str(time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")) + '.jpg'
pygame.image.save(image, str(path) + imageName)

elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
print (elapsed_time)

cam.stop()
```

However, after running the code, I get this error:

```
runfile('C:/Users/aatefi2/Downloads/robotic arm/kortex-master/kortex-master/api_python/examples/Webcam_take_picture.py', wdir='C:/Users/aatefi2/Downloads/robotic arm/kortex-master/kortex-master/api_python/examples')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-16-0e9a77e64eb6>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/aatefi2/Downloads/robotic arm/kortex-master/kortex-master/api_python/examples/Webcam_take_picture.py', wdir='C:/Users/aatefi2/Downloads/robotic arm/kortex-master/kortex-master/api_python/examples')

  File "C:\Users\aatefi2\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\aatefi2\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/aatefi2/Downloads/robotic arm/kortex-master/kortex-master/api_python/examples/Webcam_take_picture.py", line 51, in <module>
    cam = pygame.camera.Camera(0,(4096, 2160))

  File "C:\Users\aatefi2\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pygame\_camera_vidcapture.py", line 60, in __init__
    self.dev.setresolution(width, height)

Error: Cannot set capture resolution.
```

How can I solve this issue?

I appreciate any help in advance.

Thank you,

Abbas

Comment: PyGame is old and module for [camera](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/camera.html) has all time status 'EXPERIMENTAL` and probably can work only with 650x480. Try [OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55690750/change-real-camera-resolution-in-opencv)

Comment: Dear furas, I used OpenCV before but it took more than 10 sec to capture an image. I tried OpenCV again, and it takes around 3 sec. Thank you for your help.